# Specify "aud" for OneLogin JWT

Tags: onelogin

I'm adding OneLogin SSO support into our Android and iOS apps via OpenId Connect.

It's all working OK except that I can't find a way to configure the "aud" field of the JWT.

OneLogin is just putting some sort of GUID in this field, but our API requires a very specific audience value.

For other IDP's, like Azure Active Directory and Okta, this has been possible.

Does anyone know how to configure OneLogin OpenId Connect connector to specify an audience?

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure the 'aud' value in Onelogin. Appreciate you can set it in Okta, but OL sets it as a GUID.